# Access a hyperlinked cell from another cell in same sheet vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Following is a set up of my worksheet:

[image]

Cell M7 is hyperlinked to the large merged cell E6. My code needs to access the address of the destination cell from M7 (which will be E6) and assign that address to a range variable called "testing".

Once I have the address of the hyperlinked destination cell (E6) using "testing", I can then format the range address of "testing" however i want.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
Dim lcell As Range
Dim testing As Range

        testing = lcell.Hyperlinks(1).Range
        testing.Value = "TEST"
```

This gives me the following error:

```
  Run-time error: 91

  Object variable or With block variable not set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will return a reference to a hyperlink's target range whether it is the hyperlink is set by the HYPERLINK WorkSheetFunction or in the cell's hyperlink collection.

```
Sub Example()

    Dim lcell As Range
    Dim TestRange As Range

    Set lcell = Range("A1")

    Set TestRange = getHyperLinkTarget(lcell)

    If Not TestRange Is Nothing Then

        TestRange.Value = "TEST"

    End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Function getHyperLinkTarget(HSource As Range) As Range
    Dim address As String, formula As String
    formula = HSource.formula
    If HSource.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        address = HSource.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
    ElseIf InStr(formula, "=HYPERLINK(") Then
        address = Mid(formula, InStr(formula, "(") + 1, InStr(formula, ",") - InStr(formula, "(") - 1)
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    If Len(address) Then Set getHyperLinkTarget = Range(address)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Thanks to ThunderFrame for pointing out the HYPERLINK Worksheet function.

Comment: Thanks mate. However this just changes the value of the cell M7 to "TEST" instead of changing the value of cell E6 to "TEST"

Comment: The Hyperlinks collection isn't always populated, depending upon the version of Excel, and how the hyperlink is set.

Comment: @ThomasInzina when I run that code I get the error saying "subscript out of range"

Comment: Are you sure that the cell has a hyperlink?  Script out of range suggest that there was no Hyperlink in the cell.  I updated my answer to include a function that will return the target range.  You should test to see if the range returned is nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're after. You need to parse the contents of the M7 formula, so my code assumes the M7 formula *only* contains a Hyperlink formula like:

```
=HYPERLINK(E6,"RSDS")
```

And the VBA looks like:

```
Sub foo()

  Const hyperlinkSignature = "=HYPERLINK("

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Range("M7")

  Dim hyperlinkFormula As String
  hyperlinkFormula = Range("M7").formula

  Dim testing As Range

  'Check the cell contains a hyperlink formula
  If StrComp(hyperlinkSignature, Left(hyperlinkFormula, Len(hyperlinkSignature)), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    Dim hyperlinkTarget As String
    hyperlinkTarget = Mid(Split(hyperlinkFormula, ",")(0), Len(hyperlinkSignature) + 1)

    Set testing = Range(hyperlinkTarget)

    testing.Value = "TEST"

  Else
    'Check if the cell is a hyperlinked cell
    If Range("M7").Hyperlinks.Count = 1 Then
      'Credit to Thomas for this line
      Set testing = Range(Range("M7").Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress)
      testing.Value = "TEST"
    End If

  End If

End Sub
```

Or, if you want a briefer method that doesn't bother checking the M7 formula contains a hyperlink, you could use:

```
Dim target As Range
Set target = Range(Range("M7").DirectPrecedents.Address)
target.Value = "Test"
```

Comment: I wrapped the suggestion of Thomas in some checks to see what type of Hyperlink the cell contains

Comment: For some reason the WorkSheetFunction HyperLink doesn't set the Range's DirectPrecedents  property.  [Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/va5tea2ajxs837k/hyperlink.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: `Range(Range("M7").DirectPrecedents.Address)` is the same as `Range("M7").DirectPrecedents`.

Comment: hmm, there's a problem if the hyperlinked cell contains a formula like `=CONCAT(A1,B2,C3)`, the DirectPrecedents property will refer to non-contiguous range `$A$1,$B$2,$C$3`. That's (one reason) why I always prefer to use the HYPERLINK formula instead of the Insert Hyperlink functionality.

Comment: In Office 2007, I tested both types of hyperlinks and neither returned a DirectPrecedents reference.  Do they fix that in later versions?

Comment: I think the main objective should be to answer the OP's question not to handle every possible situation.  I liked your WorkSheetFunction observation.  It was a very valid point. I think the CONCATENATE issue might make an interesting question but I don't think that it is relevant to the OP.  I am trying to get a handle on your logic... I got 0...here is what I tried: `logicHandle = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", "ThunderFrame")`